# Using criteria-api to dynamic tables

Tags: java, database, jpa, criteria-api, persistence.xml

I use criteria-api to made sql query to the database and it work very fine. 
But now I need to use dynamic tables , where some tables can be create or destroyed and some column can be add or removed.

I want to manage this entityties in dynamicBean of apache, then I can create bean and edit the column.

How can I made a sql sentece using criteria-api if the bean is not in the file persistence.xml and if it is a dynamic bean?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on dynamic beans, but you may wish to investigate EclipseLink's dynamic entity support,

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/solutions/softwareasaservice002.htm#BABFJDCF